# VSCode: Replacing multiple hyphens with en- and em dashes

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

This question applies to Markdown (yes, I'm still peeved .md format doesn't interpret `--` and `---` as en and em dashes), but it could be handy for other text formats.

Is anyone aware of an extension or can suggest a method for replacing the typed sequences of `--` and `---` with `–` and `—`, respectively?

There are other markdown editors that do it, but since I'm using vscode for nearly everything else now, I'd rather do it there.

Comment: Just a minor note that `---` three or more dashes have special meaning in markdown   and used for file header, horizontal line `<hr>` and in some versions to draw tables, so it makes sense that they are not transformed automatically.

Comment: Some markdown flavours like Kramdown interpret the `---` differently if they on a line by themselves, which I think is great

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets)

```json
"– en": {
    "prefix": "--",
    "body": "–"
},
"— em": {
    "prefix": "---",
    "body": "—"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows and Mac, you can also use these keyboard shortcuts:

Em dash (—): Windows: `Alt + Ctrl + –`; Mac: `Shift + Option + -`

En dash (–): Windows: `Ctrl + –`; Mac: `Option + -`

`-` = hyphen/minus